# Interesting Undergrad Thesis

Tags: implied-volatility, finance

I'm searching for an undergrad thesis in finance. I already have some ideas, but still wanted to ask: Is there a an interesting topic that jumps to your mind, when you think about implied volatility (difficulty: beginning of master)?

Thanks in advance

Cheers

Mike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think this is allowed in this forum, but anything that has to do with using option implied volatility and skewness to estimate market betas or expected returns.

Here's a few references:

- [Measuring Equity Risk with Option-implied Correlations](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article-abstract/25/10/3113/1574288)
- [The Skew Risk Premium in the Equity Index Market](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1571700)
- [What is the Expected Return on a Stock?](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/jofi.12778)
- [The Term-Structure of Systematic Risk](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1R5YTTG3s8LxxDsZQVqfoGf6yWE_eKBcw)

Answer (score 3):

A comprehensive review of how people deal with negative interest rates in SABR / LMM and similar models could make a good thesis.